# Stackexchange.Redis why does ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect establishes two client connections?

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis

I am curious why `ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(options)` attempts to connect 2 clients to the RedisDB instead of 1? Each time I connect I see that 2 additional clients connect to my RedisDB.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because redis requires separate connections for interactive commands versus pub/sub subscriptions. If you aren't using pub/sub, you could tell the options to disable the `SUBSCRIBE` command, in which case I *believe* the second connection is not established.

Answer (score 11):

You can turn off second connection if you don't use redis pub/sub

```
var config = ConfigurationOptions.Parse(redisConnectionString);
config.CommandMap = CommandMap.Create(new HashSet<string> { "SUBSCRIBE" }, false);
connection = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(config);
```