# Two connections for each ConnectionMultiplexer?

Tags: stackexchange.redis, azure-redis-cache

I am using StackExchange.Redis to connect to azure redis cache. Everytime I do ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(....), it creates two connections in the Redis. I am checking the number of connections by using the command "Client List" in Redis. Why is it creating two connections instead of one? How can I create only a single connection?

Comment: This post is essentially the same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28145865/stackexchange-redis-why-does-connectionmultiplexer-connect-establishes-two-clien

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stackexchange.Redis why does ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect establishes two client connections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28145865/stackexchange-redis-why-does-connectionmultiplexer-connect-establishes-two-clien)

Answer (score 0):

You need to consider yourself, i.e. the connection of the admin console.

Comment: Is this an answer, or a comment for clarification? In case of the former, please read [answer] and [edit] this post to clarify how this would answer the question. If it is a comment, please delete this.